# Open recently downloaded PDF from Android push notification

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I'm prompting the user to download the PDF file in the device storage and then sending a notification that will open that file using the same Uri returned in the OnActivityResult() method. But it seems that the new Intent can't open this Uri, when I click on the notification nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
private fun firePushNotification() {
    val intent: Intent

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = uri // From OnActivityResult()
            type = "application/pdf"
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
    } else {
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = uri
            type = "application/pdf"
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
    }

    // Push logic
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
            .setContentTitle("Download concluído")
            .setContentText("Abrir PDF")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Channel 1",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).apply {
            description = ""
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
}
```

I also tried to create a File using this uri with this code:

```
private fun firePushNotification() {
    val intent: Intent

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        val input = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val file = File(context.cacheDir.absolutePath, pdfName)
        val output = FileOutputStream(file)
        copyStream(input!!, output)
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".provider", file)
            type = "application/pdf"
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
    } else {
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = uri
            type = "application/pdf"
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
    }

    // Push logic ...
}
```

`copystream()` method:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun copyStream(inp: InputStream, out: OutputStream) {
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var read: Int
    while (inp.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read)
    }
}
```

Is there another way of opening the recently downloaded file using the uri provided by the user input?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where you call `startActivity()` and pass in the intent.

so after resolving your intent, try:

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: When I create the Notification Compat Builder and pass the pendingIntent as the contentIntent it should be fired, correct?

Comment: I was mistaken, sorry. and yes, you're right. I really can't figure out why it doesn't work

Comment: tnx for you awsm answr.